# R script to HTML with knitr. Complete basics

Tags: r, knitr

I was wondering how you could turn an R script into an HTML report (From the sounds of it using knitr is the way to go). I would like to do this *without* using RStudio if possible.

Say I have to following R script

```
#Load librarys + initilisation calculations
#User shouldn't see the next 2 lines
library(foo)
set.seed(42)

#User will see the next 3 lines
print("This is some text to describe what the user is about to see")
head(mtcars)
boxplot(mtcars$mpg~mtcars$cyl)


#Not shown to user:
numbers <- runif(100)
moreNumbers <- rnorm(100)
group <- c(rep("a",100), rep("b",100))
df <- data.frame(c(numbers, moreNumbers), group)
names(df) <- c("ExampleData", "g")


#Show to user 
t.test(df$ExampleData~df$g)
```

I've tried having a look around the internet and feel as if all the steps are just a little too far ahead of what I understand.

Do I need to make another R script which contains a `stitch()/knit()` function which calls the script above?

Thanks,

Comment: you do not need Rstudio to use knitr. See http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `knitr::spin()` on your R script. Or equivalently, click the [notebook button](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/r_notebook_format.html) on the RStudio toolbar.

Comment: That's actually really close! Is there a way to suppress output from the lines of code if required?

Comment: @testuser Yes, you can use chunk options as usual, and the syntax is a little bit different, e.g. `#+ results='hide', eval=TRUE` Please see the link I included in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question about making another script is no.  What you need to do is `knit("your_script.R")` or whatever it is called.  But first, you have to make it conform to `knitr` conventions.  There are many sample files [here](http://yihui.name/knitr/) which you can use to get things correct.

Comment: So it's basically just going to require re-formatting the "your_script.R"?

Comment: You just need to edit it.  Look at the link, under demos then minimal examples.  There is a header line for each code block which tells `knitr` what to do, display it or not, and many other options.  Fixing your script above will take just a few minutes.  And if you want html as your output you should name your script with a `.Rmd` extension so `knitr` automatically creates the html.

Comment: Correction: for html output use `script.Rhtml`.  See `?knit`.